# tuning performance of a program by using different combinations of gcc options

Tags: gcc, gcc4

To my memory, there was a project to explore the best combination of gcc options(cflag)
for getting best performance of the program.

If I'm not mistaken, they do it in random test.

Could somebody reminder me about the name of the project.

It is difficult to dig from google since the project was halted.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean [ACOVEA (Analysis of Compiler Options via Evolutionary Algorithm)](http://www.coyotegulch.com/products/acovea/).

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean acovea.

http://www.coyotegulch.com/products/acovea/